# Postgresql Trigger / Transaction Behaviour

Tags: postgresql

To aid me with debugging another issue in my database, I've written the following function as a trigger in postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stage.triggerlogfunction()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    insert into stage.temptriggerlog_complete
    values
    (current_timestamp, 'Hello');
    perform pg_sleep(5);
    insert into stage.temptriggerlog_complete
    values
    (current_timestamp, 'Did');
    perform pg_sleep(5);
    insert into stage.temptriggerlog_complete
    values
    (current_timestamp, 'This Work?');
    return null;
END;
$function$
;
```

When a new row is inserted into a table in my database, this trigger is set to fire.  This works as expected, but what I was expecting to see when this ran was three rows with timestamps that are 5 seconds apart (running in sequence with a 5 second delay between each), but the actual result I had returned was three rows all with the same timestamp.

Why is this happening?  Is there a way I can force the behaviour that I was expecting?

Comment: Inside a single transaction, you only have one transaction timestamp. You're not running three transactions in you trigger.

Comment: Sorry, I realised my question is misleading.  I get that there is only one transaction - what I don't understand is why the inserts all give the same timestamp if they are running 5 seconds apart.

Comment: Ah - the penny has just dropped in that current_timestamp will just return the timestamp for the transaction as a whole.  Right - so is there any way I can get the current timestamp at the time each insert statement runs?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way I can get the current timestamp at the time each insert statement runs?

You're looking for `statement_timestamp()` (which would be the timestamp of the statement causing your trigger to fire) or even `clock_timestamp()` then.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for what they do and the alternatives.

Comment: clock_timestamp() was what I was looking for.